# CUPS: How to anonymize the filename being printed

Tags: printing, cups

When sending documents to a shared printer using CUPS, is there a convenient way to automatically hide the filename of the file being printed? In other words, I do not want administrators of the printer to be able to guess from the filename what I was printing.

Of course, a manual solution is to rename the file before printing (and possibly removing file metadata). However, I was hoping for a CUPS configuration option.

Comment: ... admins of the printer could have a filter save the complete file somewhere which might be a bigger risk than what the filename was

Comment: I am very well aware of that and there is nothing that can be done about it. However, something can be done about the metadata. And this metadata  is actually what the administrator gets to see and inspect in the first place. Call it security by obscurity.